# Non blocking shared memory producer using boost interprocess condition to notify

Tags: c++, boost, signals, shared-memory, interprocess

I am trying to develop an application with one producer and several consumers.
The producers is one process and each consumer is one process. The shared resource is some kind of buffer in the shared memory.

The producer should work completely independent from the consumers. It should not be blocked in any case. Therefor the consumers are responsible to check if the data they read from the shared memory is valid and handle it if the producer has already overwritten the data. (They do this using some kind of hashing. Not important.)

The consumers should be informed when new data is available in the buffer. I think boost interprocess conditions are suitable for this usecase. (More suitable would be boost signals2, but this library is not working in an interprocess way).

Conditionas always need a mutex. But I do not need the mutex in my producer. In the consumers I only need the mutex for condition#wait.

Is it ok to only use the codnition#notify_all in the producer and do not use the mutex? Or is this an abuse of the library?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use a pipe / FIFO that consumers read from and producers write to? You wouldn't have to deal with synchronization and it would greatly simplify the design.

Comment: I use some kind of FIFO. But I want to be notified, when new data is available in the FIFO.

Comment: Non blocking and a condition notify are contradictions.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to signal without holding the mutex, but it could lead to worst-case behaviour in rare cases (thread starvation).

Signaling under the mutex guarantees fair scheduling of the waiters under POSIX as far as I am aware ¹

That said, I think the commenters are right when they smell overcomplication in the design. I'd simplify. Optimize when you need it.

¹ See e.g. here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal

> *The `pthread_cond_broadcast()` or `pthread_cond_signal()` functions may be called by a thread whether or not it currently owns the mutex that threads calling `pthread_cond_wait()` or `pthread_cond_timedwait()` have associated with the condition variable during their waits; however, if predictable scheduling behavior is required, then that mutex shall be locked by the thread calling `pthread_cond_broadcast()` or `pthread_cond_signal()`.*

Answer (score 0):

> The producer should work completely independent from the consumers. It
>   should not be blocked in any case.

Why not? This should not affect the performance if you do not lock too frequently. You can have a data counter in shared memory and you would lock access to that counter only. Data can be stored in circular buffer in shared memory and access to it does not need to be locked because consumers check how much data is available to read using counter. Of course consumers need to read data fast enough. If the data is overwritten then the internal consumer counter can be reset to the value of interprocess counter.

Also producer can store data using many threads. Each thread can calculate future position of the data at the beginning of the thread and then update the counter after the data is stored at the end of the thread. Then additional locking is needed for future position calculations so that this value can be passed between threads.

In details, the non-multithreaded scenario could work like this:

```
Producer loop:
  receive X samples of data
  lock access to interprocess counter, increment the counter, unlock the access
```

Then each consumer has it's own internal counter so that it can compare with interprocess counter if and how much data is available to read (simply polling for data):

```
Consumer loop:
  lock access to interprocess counter, read the counter value, unlock the access
  compare the read value with internal counter
  if values equal // no data available
    sleep, then continue to the beginning of the loop
  else if data overwritten // no need for hashing here, counter can be use to figure that out although doing it this way is probably a bit risky
    set internal counter to the value of the interprocess counter
    then continue to the beginning of the loop
  else
    read available data
    increment internal counter
```